# The data inside addEventListener function is not displaying in IE where as it is working fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, addeventlistener

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onLoadFunction() {
    window.opener.postMessage({ ready: true }, window.origin);
    window.addEventListener('message', message => {
      if (message.data !== undefined) {
        var textArea = document.getElementById("txtXML");
        if (textArea !== undefined) {
          textArea.value += message.data;
          return; // Skip message in this event listener
        }
      }
    });
  }
</script>
<body onload="onLoadFunction()">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./viewXML.css">
  <textarea class="posu-textarea" disabled id="txtXML"></textarea>
</body>
```

This is html page I am having where on click of a button this page with XML data has to be displayed. But in IE it was throwing error saying `onload` function is undefined in the body section. So I have removed that `onload` in body and wrote it as `window.onload`. The console error is gone but still it's not displaying data. Tried to debug but it is not going inside the function of `addEventListener`.

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function onLoadFunction() {
      window.opener.postMessage({ ready: true }, window.origin);
      window.addEventListener('message', function (message) {
        alert(message.value);
        if (message.data !== undefined) {
          var textArea = document.getElementById("txtXML");
          if (textArea !== undefined) {
            textArea.value += message.data;
            JSON.stringify(textArea.value);
            return; // Skip message in this event listener
          }
        }
      }, false);
    }
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./viewXML.css">
  <textarea class="posu-textarea" disabled id="txtXML"></textarea>
</body*
```

What else has to be done here to display the data in IE?

Comment: Can you please inform us which version of the IE browser you are using for making this test? Try to create a function and call it on body download to check whether it works or not. If possible then try to provide an example that we can run to reproduce the issue. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue? If you had found the solution then please try to post it as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an acceptable answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. If the issue still persists then try to refer the suggestions on the thread and let us know about your status for this issue. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.